# PyTorch: Apply data augmentation on training data after random_split

Tags: pytorch, data-augmentation, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I have a dataset that does not have separate folders for training and testing. I want to apply data augmentation with transforms only on the training data after doing the split

```
 train_data, valid_data = D.random_split(dataset, lengths=[train_size, valid_size])
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? I have a custom dataset with initialization and getitem. The training and validation datasets are further passed to the DataLoader.

Comment: Do you have any method to know if that data is in training or testing folder?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a custom `Dataset` only for the transformations:

```py
class TrDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, base_dataset, transformations):
    super(TrDataset, self).__init__()
    self.base = base_dataset
    self.transformations = transformations

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.base)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    x, y = self.base[idx]
    return self.transformations(x), y
```

Once you have this `Dataset` wrapper, you can have different transformations for the train and validation sets:

```py
raw_train_data, raw_valid_data = D.random_split(dataset, lengths=[train_size, valid_size])
train_data = TrDataset(raw_train_data, train_transforms)
valid_data = TrDataset(raw_valid_data, val_transforms)
```